# modern cmake way to add glew and other opengl stuff

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm create new edu project. Here is the project structure:

```
├── 3rd-party
│   ├── glew
│   ├── glfw
│   ├── CMakeList.txt
├── src
│   ├── main.cpp
├── CMakeList.txt
```

the 3rd-party Cmakelist looks like this:

```
# GLFW
add_subdirectory(glfw)

# GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

I installed them simply with commands from github

```
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw glfw
git clone https://github.com/nigels-com/glew.git glew
```

(since glew has no CMakeList inside the root directory, I had to write find_package instead of add_subdirectory)

My main Cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Source files
add_executable(test src/main.cpp)

# dependency
add_subdirectory(3rd-party)

find_package(OpenGL)

target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC opengl32 glfw glew)
```

And i got an error:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglew
```

The linker doesn't seem to find the glew library but I don't know why, (the IDE tells me that there are no errors in Cmake itself)

I would like to have 3rd part foolder in my project structure, it's more convenient for me.

How do I fix the error? I would like to say that I'm trying to make CMake as simple as possible.

Comment: Type `cmake --help-module findglew` and it will give you help. The glew target should be `GLEW::glew` in `target_link_libraries()`

Comment: Similar goes for opengl: `cmake --help-module findopengl`

Comment: @drescherjm After I add this `GLEW::glew`  I got this: `Target "test" links to target "GLEW::glew" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?`

Comment: I am not sure that the git-clone  of the source will work.

Comment: @drescherjm what other way? i still wanna have foolder with glew

Comment: if I change `GLEW::glew` to `libglew_static` all works fine!

Comment: What is `libglew_static`? It's neither an upstream CMake target nor a lib file name which should be created if you have properly built glew with either their Makefile or CMakeLists. If glew is properly built & installed, `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` should work and define `GLEW::GLEW` (an alias of either `GLEW::glew` or `GLEW::glew_s`), just have to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to local install prefix of glew.

Comment: just checking- had you seen [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434279/11107541)? It seems relevant / similar to your question. Are you a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: First off, see this [question thread about cmake and glew](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434279/11107541). I'm thinking whether this question is a duplicate or not now...

Quoting from the maintainer of the library who wrote in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/314):

> For the purpose of a git submodule, I'd recommend using:
> [Perlmint/glew-cmake](https://github.com/Perlmint/glew-cmake) rather than this upstream repository.
>
> The long standing policy here is to maintain the history of the GLEW code generators, but not the corresponding history of the generated code. The general advice is to use the current GLEW release, rather than the in-progress master branch.
>
> I do appreciate that this arrangement is old-fashioned, but indeed GLEW has been around for a good long while.

Note on your comment that

> since glew has no CMakeList inside the root directory

It does have a CMakeLists.txt file [here under `:/build/cmake/`](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/tree/master/build/cmake). You can find discussion about its placement and the CMake situation of the library [here](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/149).

As for your immediate problem, quoting from you in the comment section:

> if I change `GLEW::glew` to `libglew_static` all works fine!